# Azure Webjobs Hangfire .Net Core 6

Tags: hangfire, asp.net-core-6.0

Can the hangfire dashboard be used with an Azure WebJob, using .Net Core 6?

Given that the hangfire extension "UseHangfireDashboard" is an extension method on IApplicationBuilder, and .Net 6 uses "IHostBuilder" in Program.cs, I don't think I have a way to use that extension method to enable the hangfire dashboard.

Is there a way to enable the hangfire dashboard using .Net Core 6 within a WebJob?

Answer (score 1):

WebJobs are not meant to host websites. Rather, they're background tasks that can run alongside a web app. So no, WebJobs aren't appropriate for hosting a website, so putting the Hangfire Dashboard there doesn't make sense. You can however host Hangfire Dashboard in an Azure Web App, and then actually run the Hangfire jobs in a separate app that runs in the context of a Web Job. Just set up their job storage (such as SQL Server) to point to the same storage.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Azure Web App
2. Deploy Hangfire job as a webjob (its working for me except for few issues)
3. Deploy a hangfire dashboard in same azure web app
4. Both should point to same Hangfire Database
5. Dashboard should show you correct hangfire job status

Note : While hosting hangfire as webjob , please make sure you are not writing anything in job directory because it may restart webjob